# Getting an unsorted set when creating it from a sorted array with duplicity

Tags: java, arrays, set, redundancy

I am taking a sorted array with some duplicate values and then to simply remove duplicity, I am adding each value into the set. As I am creating a set from a sorted array, why I am not getting a sorted set?

Here is my code:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for(int score: scores) 
        if(!(set.contains(score)))
            set.add(score);

    System.out.println(set);
```

The vale of scores is `100 100 50 40 40 20 10`

Expected output: `[100, 50, 40, 20, 10]`

Actual output: `[50, 100, 20, 40, 10]`

Comment: Why not use a `SortedSet` ?  *A Set that further provides a total ordering on its elements.*

Comment: How to implement that can you tell me please?

Comment: TreeSet is an implementation of a SortedSet

Comment: Code please I am not getting which you are trying to tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're doing `if(!(set.contains(score)))` this comparison. Then why not go for a list ? List will maintain the insertion order.

```
int scores[]= {100,100,50,40,40,20,10};
        List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int score: scores) 
            if(!(list.contains(score)))
                list.add(score);

        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

Output ::

```
[100, 50, 40, 20, 10]
```

Comment: *I see you're doing if(!(set.contains(score)))* - Good point.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine interface [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) with [`Collections.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder--) to obtain a reversed order set like below:

```
int[] scores = new int[]{100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10};
SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
for (int score : scores) { 
    set.add(score);
}
System.out.println(set); //<--it will print [100, 50, 40, 20, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Set to be sorted, use the `TreeSet`. TreeSet is a sorted set implementation , given default by Java. More info in official documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

```
Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();

for(int score: scores) 
    //if(!(set.contains(score))) # this is not needed as set already handles duplicates
        set.add(score);

System.out.println(set);
```

Comment: This will change the sort order. TreeSet will sort the data in ascending order.

Comment: You can change if you want to make it descending, with the flag in constructor.